# Best memory choice for my sensor

Tags: memory, non-volatile-memory, nand-flash

I'm a software developer and trodding in murky waters here so please do forgive my lack of knowledge. I've been developing a sensor with the nRF9160DK and some accelerometers. I need to continuously write data to a memory as the RAM is not enough to hold an entire event.

I've tried a NOR-flash, it was not fast enough, I need to write at least 32kB/s. I tried an sd-card. It was fast enough but allocating new pages took a bit too long and the power drawn was way too high. I'm now thinking of a NAND or FRAM external memory and writing via QSPI. The memory size needs to be at least 8MB which might make FRAM difficult.

Here is where I'd like help. What would you recommend? What draws the least but still fulfills the speed demands? If there is a specific product you have in mind, I'd greatly appreciate it. Or maybe an alternative, I found this that might be interesting: https://www.electrokit.com/en/product/sparkfun-openlog-2/ as it draws 2mA in idle mode though I doubt that is with the sd-cards draw included. I'm open to any recommendation to solve this! It's the last bump in a very long road I have been traveling.

I should mention I've also tried shutting down the sd-card and starting it first at en event is triggered but the mounting time is too slow(148 ms) and critical data is lost. I could save 148 ms of data in RAM but I don't think the mounting operation can be paused or multithreaded in the required way.

Thank you beforehand and please, ask if I didn't include information I did not know to be vital.

Comment: Is this a continuous write? 32kB/s doesn't seem that fast though.

Comment: Yes, 32kb/s for up to 20 seconds

Comment: Is it kB or kb? How long is downtime?

Comment: Sorry, 32kB/s. Downtime as in time between events? That could be anything from 0 seconds to many days

Comment: Some of the 64 and 32MB NAND flash I'm seeing says 50us for byte programming, 1ms for 256 byte page writes, and 2ms for 512 byte page writes. That should be more than enough except for bytewise writes. Are you writing piece meal? Or erasing pages all the time or something?

Comment: You have enough RAM to buffer almost 8 seconds of data but you say you're not buffering even 148ms? Are you trying to stream data byte by byte to storage? That sounds like a bad software decision, as it will greatly increase the demands on the storage and make block-based storage like nand highly inefficient. Can you rethink your software or are you locked into this design?

Comment: What are you using for multi-threading? Mounting the card can totally happen on a different thread than data collection, as long as they use different hardware resources.

Comment: Hey gang, I can easily buffer 148 ms and, as mentioned, more than that. I've been writing 64 bytes at a time to the sd-card as this seemed most efficient. If you can multithread this then I am happy to hear it, what worried me as a novice what that the mount procedure could not be paused in execution and then resumed due to the nature of sd-cards. I hope I might have made myself understandable. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user1850479 How would you solve the problem of mount time?

Comment: I worked on firmware for portable audio players that powered down SD cards between accesses to save battery. In that case we mounted the card once on insertion and then left it mounted while unpowered. If something tried to write the driver flipped the power back on before writing so it looked like the disk was always powered to software. That was nearly 20 years ago though and saving every last CPU cycle and microamp of battery was critical in those days.

Comment: As a first step, setup a circular buffer of X elements that match the block size of your storage. Stream data into the buffer. When one block gets full, write it out to storage in one thread while your acquisition thread (or DMA if possible) keeps writing to the new buffer. You have seconds of buffer available , so should easily be able to hide the software overhead of mounting a file system. Later, if it makes sense optimize that step out by not using a file system or putting the card to sleep while it's mounted.

Comment: @user1850479 I will try cutting of the power with a transistor and a GPIO port, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just going to address the SD card part.

First of all, for efficient writes, you must write data in blocks of 512 bytes (to match the block size*). If you write data in sizes that are not multiples of 512, or not aligned to 512 byte boundaries, the card will have to erase and rewrite each block multiple times. So, buffering is essential.

Second, you have a number of options to reduce the latency:

- use a good quality SD card rated for high speed,
- preallocate a contiguous file to the required size,
- ensure the filesystem on the SD card is not fragmented, and ideally formatted with the [official tool](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/),
- give up on the filesystem entirely, and just use the card as a block storage device.

As for multi-threading, there is no reason why that wouldn't be possible as long as the SD thread and the data collection thread don't use the same hardware resources.

** also called sector size, for some cards it might be 1024 instead of 512 — check the one you're using.*

Comment: Thank you! What an answer! 

Does the size of the sd-card affect performance? I have formatted the 32gb sd-card with the official tool and it says the clustersize are 32kB. So I should write 32kB in one swoop then? That is one second of data and there is more than enough RAM for that.

 If I were to give up on the filesystem, I have no idea how I would write data, could you care to explain the general idea and function behind this? Sorry, but this is all new to me. I'm learning as I'm going. Really appreciate the help, you have no idea.

Comment: @nwretborn briefly, cluster != sector. Maybe it's called block size in the tool? I'll get back to the other questions in a bit!

Comment: preallocating a file solved the write problem speed, I thank you for that! Now it's just the multithreading part of the mounting procedure that remains to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to address two other options:

Modern SPI/QSPI NOR flash easily supports 128-256 kByte/s continuous write bandwidth if you ensure that the sectors are pre-erased before writing.
Whether you use it in QSPI or SPI mode does not matter. The SPI bandwidth is not the bottleneck when it comes to write performance.

Standby current of flash is less than 100µA, and less than 25mA while actively writing.

You did not list non-volatility as a requirement.
There are PSRAM with SPI or QSPI interface which can handle extremely high write bandwidths. No need for pre-allocation or pre-erasing sectors.
Power consumption is similar to flash.

Comment: Thank you Timmy, it seems as though my use of the drivers are the problem and a much lower standby current of the sd-card should be reachable. I will look this over. I thank you for your knowledgeable answer